# JQuery masked input com regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Coloquei o seguinte script para colocar somente mês e ano no input, e defini o regex para aceitar a digitação de 1 até 12 para os meses:

```
            $.mask.definitions['X'] = "^([0-1]|1[0-2])$";
            jQuery(function($){
               $("#masked1").mask("X/9999");
               $("#masked2").mask("X/2015");                    
            });
```

Mas quando ponho o X, ele só permite inserir um número, então se quero colocar mês 12, não consigo. Alguém tem alguma solução?

Comment: Sua regex não deveria ser `"^([2-9]|1[0-2])$"`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa O problema é o espaçamento, quando eu ponho só um X, ele permite a digitação de somente um número, e se eu ponho "XX" , não da certo, ai ele permite digitar 22 , por exemplo.

Comment: Não vejo como você possa fazer isso dar certo (e digo do ponto de vista da usabilidade principalmente). Se o usuário digitou `1`, ele quis o mês janeiro ou ainda vai escrever outro dígito? Melhor seria exigir o zero... Quanto a evitar meses 13 ou acima, infelizmente não tenho nada a sugerir ([essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9100526/520779) e suas respostas dão a entender que não há nada pronto no plugin para fazer isso, sendo necessário customizar com código próprio). A propósito, você está usando o plugin [Masked](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), certo?

Comment: concordo com que o @mgibsonbr disse, creio não ser possível, mas lhe fornecendo a regex que creio ser a mais adequada `var r = new RegExp('^0[1-9]|1[0-2]$')`

Comment: Certo! Obrigada pelas dicas! Vou validar de um outro modo então. E sim @mgibsonbr, estou usando masked.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema? @Ysabelle Sousa

Answer (score 1):

É possível utilizar o [jquery-masked-input](/questions/tagged/jquery-masked-input), mudando a máscara com o evento `onKeyPress`, dependendo se o mês tem um valor igual a ou maior do que 10.

```js
var mask = function (val) {
    val = parseInt(val);
    return (val == 1 || val > 9)? "UD" : "N";
}

pattern = {
    onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
        field.mask(mask.apply({}, arguments), options);
    },
    translation: {
        'U': { pattern: /1/, optional: false },
        'D': { pattern: /[0-2]/, optional: false },
        'N': { pattern: /[1-9]/, optional: false }
    },
    placeholder: 'mês'
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#masked2").mask(mask, pattern);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<label>
  Mês:
  <input type="text" id="masked2" />
</label>
```